# LEFT JOIN and ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT 
    y.ID, y.STATUS, y.CONTROLID, y.TRCDE, 
    y.GST_ABSORB, y.RCODE, y.ORDNO,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), y.TRDATE, 103) AS TRDATE, y.DLYDATE, 
    y.SHPTO, y.COMNO, y.COMNO2, y.TERR, Y.CLASS, 
    y.PRDATE, y.PRNO, y.JOBNO, y.GITNO, y.DONO, y.INVNO,
    y.OFFSETNO, y.COSTYPE, y.BATCH20, y.DUPPROD, y.PROD2, v.COMNM
FROM 
    YTDTRNI AS y 
LEFT JOIN 
    VND AS v ON y.COMNO = v.COMNO 
ORDER BY 
    y.TRDATE DESC
```

The result of this query is correct. However, if I change the `ORDER BY` clause such that it does not include the alias of the table, like this:

```
SELECT y.ID,
    y.STATUS,
    y.CONTROLID,
    y.TRCDE,
    y.GST_ABSORB,
    y.RCODE,
    y.ORDNO,
    CONVERT(varchar(10),y.TRDATE,103) AS TRDATE,
    y.DLYDATE,
    y.SHPTO,
    y.COMNO,
    y.COMNO2,
    y.TERR,
    Y.CLASS,
    y.PRDATE,
    y.PRNO,
    y.JOBNO,
    y.GITNO,
    y.DONO,
    y.INVNO,
    y.OFFSETNO,
    y.COSTYPE,
    y.BATCH20,
    y.DUPPROD,
    y.PROD2,
    v.COMNM 
FROM YTDTRNI AS y LEFT JOIN
        VND AS v ON y.COMNO = v.COMNO 
ORDER BY TRDATE DESC
```

the ordering of the `TRDATE` column of the result becomes messed up.

It will show results with `TRDATE` shown in this sequence:

```
31/12/2012
31/12/2012
31/03/2008
30/06/2018
```

Is the problem occurring due to the use of the alias or the convert function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first query where you provide a qualified field name (`y.TRDATE`), the results are ordered by the actual `TRDATE` value in your `YTDTRNI` table - which, I would assume, is a date field of some kind (`date`, `datetime`, `datetime2` or similar). In this instance date ordering rules apply and you get the expected sort result.

In the second query you are ordering by the derived `TRDATE` value which is returned as part of the result set - which is `varchar(10)` - and therefore string (rather than date) ordering rules apply.

Answer (score 1):

You have aliased the result of `CONVERT` to be named `TRDATE` - so `TRDATE` and `y.TRDATE` refer to different things:

```
CONVERT(varchar(10),y.TRDATE,103) AS TRDATE
```

When you order by `TRDATE`, you are ordering by the result of this conversion. However, when you order by `y.TRDATE`, you are ordering by the original column in the `YTDTRNI` table.

in the interests of well-maintained code, you may wish to change the name of the alias for the conversion result, so that when someone needs to maintain this, it's obvious what is happening.